# SSL: Intermediate certificate compromised -- Can they unrevoke a certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using certs from an issuer called AlphaSSL. I just recently realised that my pages shows invalid certificate error on pageload. Further investigation shows that the intermediate certificate that binds my cert to GlobalSign's root certificate has been revoked. I checked and there is a [new intermediate certificate on their site](https://secure.alphassl.com/cacert/gsalphag2.crt) but I am not sure I should download it as their download page is secured with the same revoked certificate.

UPDATE:

I got a boilerplate email from support, they reckon clearing the CRL cache should fix the issue. I wonder though, is this really doable, can they 'unrevoke' the certificate? How can I check **their** revocation list and how can I force the propagation of the undo to my CRL (other than clearing the cache)?

UPDATE2:

I received another email that references [this page](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/2599710-ocsp-revocation-errors---troubleshooting-guide%C2%A0). Long story short, they are busy shoveling the sh*t back to the horse, browser ubiquity yaddda-yadda, you should change the iterim cert to a new one, but if you have AlphaSSL or CLoudSSL, then you're sheesh out of luck, no cert for you.

Does not say where to claim your money back.

Comment: Ad your programming-question is?

Comment: IS there a trivial way to move the question to ServerFault? 
Edit: prolly there isn't, I cant even log on to ServerFault with my SO creds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GlobalSign is currently experiencing issues which results in certificates being marked as revoked:

https://twitter.com/globalsign/status/786505261842247680

Answer (score 1):

I got a reply from their support staff:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for getting in touch with the GlobalSign Support Team
>
> We thank you for bringing this to our attention. We are aware of the
>   issue you described and are in the process of investigating the matter
>   further.
>
> We would like to ask for the below details so we can provided these to
>   the team investigating the issue.
>
> Operating system & version: Browsers & version:
>
> For the latest updates on the issue, please follow the below link:
>   https://twitter.com/gssystemalerts
>
> We will let you know as soon as the issue has been resolved.
>
> Thanks.
>
> Best Regards, Janice Tablarin GlobalSign Support Team

Some boilerplate response, I reckon. If the trust has gone from the cert that signed a zillion other certs, then its not a cliient/browser issue.